# Logging to temporary directory in a cross-platform manner

Tags: log4j, temporary-files

I have an application for which log4j logging is configured in a log4j.properties file.  Currently, this application runs on UNIX and creates a log file in /tmp.  This application needs to run on Windows, and on that platform I would like for it to select the correct temporary directory, which I believe is C:\temp.

How can I change my log4j.properties file to make this happen?  Do I need to switch to using an XML configuration file?

Comment: While writing this question I may have found the answer.  I haven't tested yet, though, and I'll vote people up and accept a good answer for a chance for someone else to score some rep.  If I feel I have something to add, I'll post my answer and people can vote up or down as they feel.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you would just use `${java.io.tmpdir}` in place of a hard-coded path.

Comment: Just as a side note, this variable works in Logback's config file too.

Comment: In my yaml config I had to use `${sys:java.io.tmpdir}` (sys: prefix) to make it work

Comment: Can you please explain how this works? I can't seem to find reference this type of lookup in log4j documentation.

Answer (score 1):

As of Log4J v1.2.14, I was able to use this in both a log4j.xml file as well as a log4j.properties file.  There was some discussion on the web that variables wouldn't parse in the DOMReader, but they do as of this version of log4j.

```
<appender name="rolling_file_appender_ourapp" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="${user.home}/.mycompany/OurApp.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="false" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="3" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d | %-5p | %c | %m | %t | %x %n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

or

```
log4j.appender.rfile=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.rfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rfile.Append=false
log4j.appender.rfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%p] %c %m%n
log4j.appender.rfile.File=${user.home}/.mycompany/OurApp.log
```

Comment: Would the slash in the "File" parameter value be interpreted correctly on a Microsoft OS, i.e. as a backslash, or would I need to use the file separator property?

Comment: @TomislavNakic-Alfirevic the latter or "\\"

Comment: Java automagically converts slashes (`/`) to the OS-dependent directory separator in filenames, so `/` usually "just works".